# Не удаётся создать новую пару ключ-значение словаря в функции

Tags: python

Не удаётся создать новую пару ключ-значение {'age' : age}. В чём может быть проблема?

```
def build_person(first_name, last_name):
    person = {'first': first_name, 'last': last_name}
    if age:
        person['age'] = age
    return person
musician = build_person('dan', 'balan', age = 23)
print('\n' + musician)
```

Comment: этот код не будет исполняться. функция ожидает 2 параметра, вы передаете 3

Comment: Задача состоит в том, чтобы добавить новый параметр

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете сделать таким образом: добавлять произвольные именованные параметры. Или фильтровать этот список в функции, если нужно контролировать входные дапнные

```
def build_person(first_name, last_name, **kwargs ):
    person = {'first': first_name, 'last': last_name}
    for x in kwargs:
        person[x] = kwargs[x]
    return person
musician = build_person('dan', 'balan', age = 23)
print(musician)   # {'first': 'dan', 'last': 'balan', 'age': 23}
```